# XML Unicode deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, xml-deserialization

I have an XML file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <student name="Adnand"/>
     <student name="özil"/>
     <student name="ärnold"/>
</students>
```

As you see, I have an **UTF-8** **encoding**, but I have used some non UTF-8 characters (ö, ä).

I use the following code to deserialize this XML:

```
public void readXML(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);       
    object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Students myStudents = (Students)obj;
}
```

The deserialization process it's ok, but the special characters are shown as � symbol. I tryed changing the encoding type, but nothing. Can someone help me what alternatives I have?

**ANSWER**
You should specify the Encoding.Default like

```
public void readXML(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default);       
    object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Students myStudents = (Students)obj;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8);` would work?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I tried also the other encoding formats.

Comment: There are no non-UTF-8 characters. UTF-8 lets you encode all the Unicode characters.

Comment: Have you also tried `Encoding.Default`? maybe your file is indeed not encoded as UTF-8

Comment: Yes, the Encoding.Default make the job. Thank you. Please edit the answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: How do you ascertain that it doesn't work? Did you look at the results in a debugger or in a console window?  Because I think it just should have worked.

Comment: @bommelding your solution may work also, but I may need to change my whole code to implement it.

Comment: Sorry I mees it up with Marco Salernos solution. It doesn't work it without specifying the default encoding, I don't know why. I looked the results in debugger and also the results stored on my database.

Comment: `ö, ä` **are** UTF8 characters. This page is a UTF8 page which is why you can see those characters in the first place. Is your actual *file* stored as a UTF8 file though, or is it an ANSI file that just happens to have the text `UTF-8` in the encoding attribute?

Comment: @Adnand btw UTF8 works without extra effort. If you have problems it's because the file is *not* using the UTF-8 encoding. Save it again as UTF8 or convert it.

Comment: You need to find out why the actual file encoding differs from that specified in the declaration. And to eliminate this discrepancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your file is not encoded as `UTF-8` but as Window's default `ANSI` encoding.

Defining the StreamReader as

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default)
```

should do the trick.

---

Note that this is more of a workaround and using `Encoding.Default` is actually a very *bad* idea since it will break when using another Culture. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2005/03/15/dont-use-encoding-default/) gives a nice overview why you should not use `Encoding.Default` (thanks to Alexander for sharing). It's better to use UTF-8 as most systems can deal with it.

In your specific case to actually save the file as UTF-8 you either have to:

- Adapt the program that creates the file to output it as UTF-8
- Or if you used a text editor to create the file, use a text editor that supports UTF-8 encoding (e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: It works on a machine with one culture, but will break on a machine with another culture. 
[Don’t Use Encoding.Default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2005/03/15/dont-use-encoding-default/)

Comment: Yeah I'm totally with you. I'll edit my answer to emphasize on not using Encoding.Default...

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamReader to specify encoding

```
var Students xmlObject = null;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inXML, Encoding.UTF8, true)) {
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
    xmlObject = (Students)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
}
```

Also have you tried using the Encoding "ISO-8859-1", I use this mostly for foreign characters

Comment: Still nothing. Where should I specify the Encoding "ISO-8859-1"?

Comment: Since its not a default one, use GetEncoding(string) →
new StreamReader(inXML, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), true)

Comment: @Adnand instead of trying multiple encodings *fix the file*. If it says "UTF-8" the file should be saved as UTF8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it should be like you say, but I just use the file, I am not the creator.

Comment: @Adnand Can you send it back in a bug report with the suggestion of using a library to write XML documents so that it would write the encoding declaration to match the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("icsemmelle.xml");
        List<XElement> xStudents = xDocument.Descendants("student").ToList();
        foreach(XElement xStudent in xStudents)
        {
            students.Add(new Student { Name = xStudent.Attribute("name").Value });
        }
    }
}

class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, XLinq has no problem with the chars but this needs manual deserialization.

Comment: Actually he asked for alternatives, this way most of the possible problems are already handled

Comment: @MarcoSalerno LINQ has nothing to do with encodings. If it works, it's because the file is UTF8 and the deserialization was succesful

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fortunally you told me, it wasn't obvious before

Comment: @MarcoSalerno if it was, why this code that doesn't affect the result at all? If you tried to use that code with an ANSI file you'd still get `�`

Comment: Cause the problem was the approach itself

Comment: @MarcoSalerno this answer doesn't show a different approach. It's not even related

Comment: @MarcoSalerno why don't you try it first, with an *ANSI* file that *doesn't* match your machine's locale? And search SO for other questions related to the Unicode replacement character? If you really insist you might even [check the source code](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/dotnet/corefx/src/System.Xml.XDocument/src/System/Xml/Linq/XDocument.cs#261) and see it doesn't do anything special. It's just a call to XmlReader.Create

Comment: Considering that the file is an utf-8 my code is eprfectly working for sure

Comment: @MarcoSalerno the file is not UTF8 even though it has that value in the `encoding` tag. A UTF8 *file* is one *saved* using the UTF8 encoding. That's why the problem occured in the first place and why the accepted answer worked. You didn't *try* your code with an non-Unicode file yet. Try it.

Comment: So the OP asked for a solution fora different problem. He clearly states that the encoding is correct.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno yes, the OP is correct. You misunderstand what encoding means. It's not the value of the `encoding` tag. It's the **file's** actual encoding, which has to do with which bytes are stored for each character. It's what you pass to the `Encoding` parameter of file readers, writers, calls to `File.WriteAllText` etc

Comment: @MarcoSalerno to try it, save the question's text with `File.WriteAllText(..,...,Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))` and then try your code. Instead of `özil` you'll get `ozil`

Comment: I'm not talking about the encoding tag value.